# Smallest number an a Array

Tags: python-3.x, command-line, arraylist

I'm trying to get an array of numbers through the command line prompt and then have my program print out the smallest number in that array, but with the program below I cant seem to get it to print anything at all I'm not even receiving any errors so I have no idea where I've messed up at...

```
import sys
from List import *

def main(int,strings):
    myArray = (sys.argv[1])
    strings = myArray(sys.argv[1:])
    numbers = (int,strings)
    result = (sys.argv[1])
        for i in range(0,len(strings),1):
        transformed = int(strings[i])
        result.append(transformed)
    return result
    smallest = numbers[0]
    for i in range(1,len(numbers),1):
        if(numbers[i] < smallest):
            smallest = numbers[i]
    print ("The smallest number is", smallest)


main
```

Comment: you're not calling `main`.  You need parentheses after it to call it.  Also you `return` before you `print` anything.

Comment: I was trying to use the Map Pattern to convert the argument strings into ints then return it, after that use the extreme pattern to print out the smallest number in that array

Comment: **python -c 'import sys; print(min(map(int,sys.argv[1:])))' 2 3 4 5** outputs 2

Answer (score 0):

Someone did comment, and said "you're not calling main. You need parentheses after it to call it. Also you return before you print anything." - roippi. That essentiall says it all.

The way functions work, is that it stops, and ends the function when it comes across a 'return' statement; and as you can see, the return statement cuts off half the function. Also, you aren't calling the function, nor are you passing it any parameters.